# How to receive all request parameters in a model in Java Struts2?

Tags: java, object, parameters, struts2, request

I am trying to receive all the request parameters from a form in controller having a modelobj. But the model parameters remains null. I dont want to create all the parameters and their setter/getters of models in my controller class...Plz help

Form :

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form action="login" method="post">
    <label>Email Id</label>
    <input type="text" name="emailId">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Model :

```
public class UserModel {
    String emailId;
    String password;
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginController extends ActionSupport{
    UserModel userModelObj = new UserModel();
    public UserModel getUserModelObj() {
        return userModelObj;
    }
    public void setUserModelObj(UserModel userModelObj) {
        this.userModelObj = userModelObj;
    }
    public String login()
    {
        UserModel userModelObj = new UserModel();
        System.out.println(userModelObj.emailId);
        System.out.println(userModelObj.password);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

On console it returns null null

Comment: And remove this `= new UserModel()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use your bean class reference in your form's name attribute like this :

```xml
<div>
    <form action="login" method="post">
        <label>Email Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="userModelObj.emailId"/>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="userModelObj.password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</div>
```

Otherwise use the concept Of ModelDriven interface.

Comment: It would be better to use struts tags, though.

Comment: yeah definitely he should, as this is one of the most important feature of struts2

Comment: Also if anyone can tell me.. how can i make and use app constants in java/struts2(and where).  In php/zend i used to create constants.EMAIL_ID = emailId; and was able to use it anywhere like userModelObj.EMAIL_ID;

Comment: @ user2955532  whom do you want to make constants, the data which is  coming from a textfield emailId??

Comment: @Sahil no constants of field names(variable names) like database name so that i can change it at one place and it reflects at all other places...

Comment: @user2955532 You can still use constants if you prefer it.